# determine the value of $k$ so that $x-1$ is a factor of $2x^3-(k+1)x^2+6kx+11$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The remainder for this is suppose to equal $0$, determine the value of $k$ so that $x-1$ is a factor of $2x^3-(k+1)x^2+6kx+11$.

Comment: What does the polynomial remainder theorem tell you?  Precisely where are you stuck? What are your efforts thus far?

Comment: I've tried synthetic division but when I got my answer for k it was 2.8 and when I plugged the numbers in it gave me a remainder of 26 so I thought something was wrong with the way I was doing it

Comment: Fine, but – do you know the remainder theorem?

Comment: Like plug in +1 in the formula?

Comment: @oogabooga Please write in mathematical language (Latex).

Comment: The remainder theorem isn't "plug in $+1$ in the formula". The remainder theorem has a clearly stated hypothesis, and a clearly stated conclusion. Do you know it, oogabooga?

Answer (score 1):

For $x=1$ , $2*1^3-(k+1)*1^2+6k*1+11=0$ because 1 is a root of $P(x) = 2x^3-(k+1)x^2+6kx+11 = (x-1)Q(x)$.

So $ 2-k-1+6k+11=0$ and then $k =-2.4$

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that you did the synthetic division. Does it look like this?

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
1 & 2 & -(k+1) & 6k & 11\\
& & \color{blue}2&\color{blue}{1-k}&\color{red}{-11}\\ \hline
&\color{blue}2&\color{blue}{1-k}&\color{red}{1+5k}& 0
\end{array}

In blue and red is the division process. In red is a linear equation $$1\cdot(1+5k)=-11$$
which has the solution $\boxed{k=-\dfrac{12}5}$.

---

Notice that you get the same linear equation to solve using the polynomial remainder theorem:

$$f(x) \div (x-p) \implies f(p) =R.$$

Let $f(x)=2x^3-(k+1)x^2+6k+11$.  Setting the remainder to be $0$, we get
\begin{align}f(x)\div (x-1) \implies f(1) =0&=2(1)^3-(k+1)(1)^2+6k(1)+11\\
0&=2-k-1+6k+11\\
5k&=-12\\
k&=-\frac{12}5
\end{align}

Comment: So like I had that exactly and I got 2 -(k+3) 5k+3 and I think my calculations I did were wrong

Comment: @oogabooga I edited my answer for the solution.